# Pressure change caused by rotation contradiction (Rotating fluid in a bucket)

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, centrifugal-force

I am reading through this [article](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2832417&seqNum=7) which analyzes the pressure in the liquid rotating in a cylindrical container, in it there are two expressions derived for height of the liquid which seem to be contradicting:

1. The expression from equating pressure differential across area to centripetal force:

$$ p= \frac12 \omega^2 r^2 \tag{1}$$

Where $\omega$ is angular speed , $r$ is distance  from center of rotation

2. From the hydrostatic pressure from the vertex of parabola

$$ p = \rho gz \tag{2}$$

$z$ is height from vertex

The contradiction I find is that (1) says that $p$ is independent of $z$ while equation two suggests that $p$ is independent of $r$ because $r$ and $z$ are independent variables. Hence, these two formulas 'should' be contradicting each other, what am I missing?

Comment: It looks to me like the point of the article is that the water finds a shape, $z(r)$, where both of these are consistent, ie, Eq. 1.47  Or am I misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I don't think $z$ is a single valued function of $r$, for example for a given radius 'r' , there are many heights 'r'... unless we are speaking only about the concave surface of the paraboloid @tom10

Comment: Yes, I think it's calculating $z(r)$ at the surface by equating the pressures at a disk at the apex. That is, the pressure at $P$ (and the set of $P$ form a horizontal disk) in Fig. 1.20(a) can be calculated in two different ways and then these pressures are set equal since they are both the pressure at the same point. This forms a relationship between $r$, which is used for the pressure as calculated along the $OP$ (horiz) path, and $z$, which is used for the pressure as calculated from the $QP$ (vert) path. So the pressure calculated at the disk determines the shape of the surface $z(r)$.

Comment: There is still another problem, consider a height above the vertex of 'h' now according to (2) all points at height must have rho g z but according to (1), it seems that the pressure increases radially outwards again. @tom10

Comment: The equations are only derived for the disk at the apex, and don't apply everywhere. It's basically asking, "what shape of the surface will make the points on the disk at the apex be in equilibrium?" There is no guarantee that these equations apply everywhere, and they clearly don't. For example, below the parabola, it's easy to see that one would need to add a depth term to the radial equation. But it's not there in the equation! Why not? Because the equation isn't applicable to that depth, and only applies to the disk at the apex as shown in Fig. 1.20(a).

Answer (score 1):

Your second equation is the pressure increase which occurs as you go down from the surface to an element of fluid at a depth, z.  The pressure increment is the same for each small step going down.  The first expression (which should include a density) is the pressure increase which occurs as you move horizontally from the surface to the same element at a radius, r.  In this case, the pressure increment increases with, r, and that has to be integrated to get the total change.  In both cases you are looking at a pressure change from the surface to a given element of the fluid.  They should agree as long as the element is higher than the bottom of the dip in the surface.

Comment: "Your second equation is the pressure increase which occurs as you go down from the surface to an element of fluid at a depth, z." I don't think so this is correct, in the link , they had referenced the height from vertex of paraboloid as far as I Understand

Comment: Good point.  That puts the fluid element at the same level as the bottom of the parabola, and, z, measures  from there up to the surface.